# Columns named 'True' and 'False' in pandas don't work and refuse to rename

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, boolean, rename

I was working with pivoting the table and some columns received names "True" and "False". I tried to call them but it didn't work

```
hardest_and_easiest_assesment.True

  File "<ipython-input-47-4348b732cff9>", line 1
    hardest_and_easiest_assesment.True
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I figured that it was because of the Boolean names so I tried to rename them but it didn't work.

```
hardest_and_easiest_assesment.rename(columns={'id_assessment':'IdAssessment','True':'Success'})
```

After this the pandas show the column 'True' with the old label. Where is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. `rename` is not inplace, you need assign it back

```py
hardest_and_easiest_assesment = hardest_and_easiest_assesment.rename(columns={'id_assessment':'IdAssessment','True':'Success'})
```

2. If column name is boolean type, `'True'` is string which doesn't match with boolean. You need change string to boolean

```py
hardest_and_easiest_assesment = hardest_and_easiest_assesment.rename(columns={'id_assessment':'IdAssessment',True:'Success'})
```

3. If column name is boolean type, you can access it with

```py
hardest_and_easiest_assesment[True]
```